# Boostrap Modal example doesn't show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm testing Bootstrap Modal example "[live demo](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/)" and I've included bootstrap jquery and js in [bootstrap starter template](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/), and also the custom javascript:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myInput').focus()
})
```

but the modal run from my text editor doesn't show like the one on their website does. I click the button and nothing happens. 
I've tried using Google Chrome Inspector/console and it shows:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

at the line where the function starts. When I remove the custom js, it doesn't show error but still the modal doesn't show on Chrome, Edge or Firefox.

*My code is just the combination of Bootstrap starter template and its modal live demo code in the body so there's no need to post the code here.*

Also, please note that I could make the code work (the button works like the example shown on boostrap website) by assigning an id to the button:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" id="button">
```

then add a custom function later:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>   $("#button").click(function() {
>       $('.modal').modal('show');
>   });
> </script>
> ```

However, that's not the same as the sample code provided by Bootstrap.

Comment: you forgot to load jquery.min.js

Comment: you may please mention your html code also

Comment: You must use Jquery before bootstrap.js

Comment: Thank you guys. Yes, the error was because the custom js was put before the jquery was loaded. If I put it below the links to jquery by bootstrap, the error doesn't show. However, the button still doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions. I've found out the answer: 
The sample code by bootstrap has an error:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

the `data-target=""` should contain the id of the modal, which, in this case is #myModal not #exampleModal.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this error occurs because you're trying to use JQuery without having referenced it in your project first.

Try adding the following to the top your page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you G.Hunt. Your code stops the error message if I put the custom js on top. If I put the custom js on the bottom of the body, it's not needed since there are already links to jquery by bootstrap starter. Still the button doesn't do anything.

Answer (score -1):

it means you are running your script before document is ready. Try this

```
$(function(){
   $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
     $('#myInput').focus()
   })
});
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the asker's problem is with `$` (aka Jquery), not DOM loading.

Comment: Yes because jquery has not been loaded yet. That's the reason he is getting `$ undefined` error.

Comment: Jquery not being loaded yet and the document not being loaded yet are two different things.

Comment: Thank you Serdar but your suggestion doesn't work. Also, I didn't down-vote you. Any suggestion is appreciated.